# Proplem in registration page, wordpress website

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I have got an error on the registration page for my wordpress
https://www.trteebook.com/wp-login.php?action=register

This is the error
خطأ فى قاعدة بيانات ووردبريس: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" med...' at line 1]insert into wp_job_ipcache (ipnr, country, info) values('5.162.129.106, 172.70.147.15','','              Attention Required! | Cloudflare        body{margin:0;padding:0}   if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) { window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { var cookieEl = document.getElementById('cookie-alert'); cookieEl.style.display = 'block'; }) }      Please enable cookies.   Sorry, you have been blocked You are unable to access ipinfodb.com            Why have I been blocked? This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.

What can I do to resolve this? You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.      Cloudflare Ray ID: 6f9ac8a98c81909d • Your IP: 2a02:4780:8:d::f • Performance & security by Cloudflare      window._cf_translation = {};    ')

Comment: You have some code that is not checking for errors after requesting something, and the thing you're requesting had blocked you. More importantly, you've accidentally trusted that external site to inject SQL commands into your database; if they wanted to annoy you, they could have deleted all your content. See the attached question for what you should do about it.

Comment: all my content still there in my website, nothing changed all this error to my registration page.

Comment: I didn't say anyone *had* deleted your content, I just wanted to highlight how dangerous the bug could be if somebody decided to exploit it, and how urgent it is to fix it.